# Customize JFileChooser to set Previewer below file list

Tags: java, swing, layout, customization, jfilechooser

I need a FileDialog with preview panel to show images. I can use JFileChooser to set everything I need, the Only thing I can't find to do is to set Location of Accessory component. 
I want Previewer to be between files list and File Name text field. I can find Accesory component being added on the right of file List only.

Is It possible to set it between fileList & filename text Field ? What can be the alternative with all JFileChooser features ?

Comment: not supported - if you are desperate, you might try to remove/add the preview of the chooser after it has been created (look at the sources of the ui-delegates to see which Layoutmanager is used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my comment: a quick&dirty approach is to add the accessory component to the component containing the file list. It is a custom panel of type FilePane with BorderLayout, at its own center the list/table, so you can add the accessory to its south. In the simplest case (for Metal/Nimbus), the chooser's center itself is-the FilePane and the snippet below can be used directly. For other LAFs (f.i. Windows) you need to dig deeper into the center component, until you find the parent of the list/table.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
JComponent panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JButton("my dummy Accessory"));
panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
chooser.setAccessory(panel);

JComponent center = null;
BorderLayout layout = (BorderLayout) chooser.getLayout();
for (Component child : chooser.getComponents()) {
    if (BorderLayout.CENTER == layout.getConstraints(child)) {
        center = (JComponent) child;
    }
}
if (center != null)
    center.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Beware:

- it's relying on implementation details, thus brittle
- it's highly LAF dependent
- it won't survive a LAF toggle at runtime